Azure Devops Cache Task's file is 0mb
Context: I'm trying to cache the 700mb+ mongodb installer so that on every single run, we do not need to re-download. Ive been advised to implement the Cache@2 task.
I've been trying to get the Cache@2 task working the last few days and have some mixed results. Below is basically the version I had working, i.e. cache hit, and downloaded files of 700mbish successfully, here is some of the output which clarifies there was data downloaded:
Cache choco step output

Download statistics: Total Content: 746.7 MB Physical Content
Downloaded: 744.8 MB Compression Saved: 1.9 MB Local Caching Saved:
0.0 MB Chunks Downloaded: 9,684 Nodes Downloaded: 19

install mongodb from cache step output

mongodb.install v7.3.2 [Approved] mongodb.install package files
install completed. Performing other installation steps.
C:\ProgramData\MongoDB\data\db C:\ProgramData\MongoDB\log File appears
to be downloaded already. Verifying with package checksum to determine
if it needs to be redownloaded.

All was good, however once I merged in my code to main, the cache was no longer working, and was back to dowloading mongodb every single run. My theory was some sort of fingerprint mismatch given the cache was created on a branch and this was the output I noticed on the previously successful run:

Used scope:
725;aa241718-ddab-43ea-928e-e8e2cdcbc850;refs/heads/pipelinepoc;f5e3a496-969c-496a-a516-0b8dec7a0f62

So I came back and created a new branch, with a new name and ran it, and it also had a cache miss, then errord with the post cache task saying:

tar: could not chdir to 'D:\a\1\s\mongo_db_cache'

I've now added a create directory step, and the current situation is, there is always a cache hit, however the files to be downloaded are 0.0mb:

ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with
X-TFS-Session 66dc6bf2-188e-4285-b998-04ba7dda384d Hashtype: Dedup64K
Getting a pipeline cache artifact with one of the following
fingerprints: Fingerprint: mongodb-server There is a cache hit:
mongodb-server Used scope:
725;aa241718-ddab-43ea-928e-e8e2cdcbc850;refs/heads/postmergechanges;f5e3a496-969c-496a-a516-0b8dec7a0f62
Entry found at fingerprint: mongodb-server Expected size to be
downloaded: 0.0 MB Downloaded 0.0 MB out of 0.0 MB (214%). Downloaded
0.0 MB out of 0.0 MB (214%).
Download statistics: Total Content: 0.0 MB Physical Content
Downloaded: 0.0 MB Compression Saved: 0.0 MB Local Caching Saved: 0.0
MB Chunks Downloaded: 3

Below is my code, I feel like it has created the cache empty on one of the runs, and now will not back fill it, but honestly im clutching at straws on this. Google does not seem to through up much about this, but I know it can work because it was working before I merged into main. Can anyone work out how to get this working once and for all!
variables:
  - group: integration-common

  - name: CACHE_RESTORED
    value: 'false'

trigger: 
  - master

pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
  vmImage: windows-2022

stages:
- stage: Build_and_Test
  displayName: 'Build, Test and Publish'
  jobs:

  - job:
    displayName: 'Download and Cache MongoDB Atlas'
        
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      fetchDepth: 0

    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: 'New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/mongo_db_cache'

    - task: Cache@2
      displayName: 'Cache choco'
      inputs:
        key: 'mongodb-server'
        restoreKeys: 'mongodb-server'
        path: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/mongo_db_cache'   
        cacheHitVar: CACHE_RESTORED

    - script: choco install mongodb --confirm --no-progress
      displayName: 'install mongodb from choco'
      condition: ne(variables.CACHE_RESTORED, 'true')

    - script: choco install mongodb --confirm --no-progress --cache $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/mongo_db_cache
      displayName: 'install mongodb from cache'
      condition: ne(variables.CACHE_RESTORED, 'false')
    

    - script: | 
        mkdir "c:\\data\db"
        mkdir "c:\\log"
        mongod --dbpath "c:\\data\db" --port 27017 --serviceName "mongodb-choc" --logpath="c:\\log.txt" --serviceDisplayName "mongodb-choc" --install"
        net start mongodb-choc
      displayName: start mongodb
    


Hi JsonStatham, as you mentioned that ' it was working before I merged into main', you can also compare the script task with the one in that branch to find the difference between them.

It is because in your 'install mongodb from choco' task, you didn't add the --cache $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/mongo_db_cache in the choco command.
This caused the error "could not chdir to 'D:\a\1\s\mongo_db_cache'". To solve the error, you created the folder $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/mongo_db_cache, but it is still empty, and you cashed the empty folder. That is why you are downloading the 0 mb files.
Modified yaml:
variables:
  - group: integration-common

  - name: CACHE_RESTORED
    value: 'false'

trigger: 
  - master

pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
  vmImage: windows-2022

stages:
- stage: Build_and_Test
  displayName: 'Build, Test and Publish'
  jobs:

  - job:
    displayName: 'Download and Cache MongoDB Atlas'
        
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      fetchDepth: 0


    # This is not needed. 
    # - task: PowerShell@2
    #   inputs:
    #     targetType: 'inline'
    #     script: 'New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/mongo_db_cache'

    - task: Cache@2
      displayName: 'Cache choco'
      inputs:
        key: 'mongodb-server'
        restoreKeys: 'mongodb-server'
        path: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/mongo_db_cache'   
        cacheHitVar: CACHE_RESTORED

    - script: choco install mongodb --confirm --no-progress --cache $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/mongo_db_cache
      displayName: 'install mongodb from choco'
      condition: ne(variables.CACHE_RESTORED, 'true')

    - script: choco install mongodb --confirm --no-progress --cache $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/mongo_db_cache
      displayName: 'install mongodb from cache'
      condition: ne(variables.CACHE_RESTORED, 'false')
    

    - script: | 
        mkdir "c:\\data\db"
        mkdir "c:\\log"
        mongod --dbpath "c:\\data\db" --port 27017 --serviceName "mongodb-choc" --logpath="c:\\log.txt" --serviceDisplayName "mongodb-choc" --install"
        net start mongodb-choc
      displayName: start mongodb

